# How to get strings from array randomly without repeating the string?

Tags: android, arrays, string

I'm making a quiz app I have string array and I want to load them on button click, strings should be loaded randomly into Text View. Strings should not be repeated.

Thanks..

Comment: Use `Collections.shuffle()` and get the value with incremented  index each time until its reaches the bound .

Answer (score 0):

Because it's your quiz, I'm gonna give you hints not the whole soltion

```
Random rnd = new Random;
while(array.size()>0){
    // 1. use rng to get a index between 0 to current array.size()
    // 2. remove the string by array.remove(index) so that it won't duplicated.
    // 3. setText(string)
}
```

Try this, you can add comments if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to convert the array to a list and shuffling it.

```
List myList = Arrays.asList(yourArray);
Collections.shuffle(myList);
```

After that you can just iterate over the list.